# How to print the line having GET between time range using regex Python

Tags: python, regex, file, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

My Log file is below. Need to find the line having GET and running between 2018-07-11 10 and 2018-07-11 11

`2018-07-11 10:12:06 12.115.14.240 "PUT /apng/assembler-2.0/assembler2.php HTTP/1.1" 403 231 "http://littlesvr.ca/apng/history.html" 
2018-07-11 10:15:06 202.167.250.99 "GET /apng/images/o_sample.png?142475198 HTTP/1.1" 403 115656 "http://bbs.mydigit.cn/read.php" 
2018-07-11 11:16:06 120.115.144.240 "GET /apng/assembler-2.0/assembler2.php HTTP/1.1" 200 231 "http://littlesvr.ca/apng/history.html"`

```
with open(log) as f:
    log = f.read()
    ###if condition to show to get GET
          line = re.search(rx,log)
```

Desired Out
`2018-07-11 10:15:06 202.167.250.99 "GET /apng/images/o_sample.png?142475198 HTTP/1.1" 403 115656 "http://bbs.mydigit.cn/read.php"`

Comment: Do not use `log = f.read()`. Use `for line in f:` and then `if '"GET ' in line: print(line)`.

Answer (score -1):

I think regex will work:

```py
rx=r"^2018-07-11 1(0|1).*GET"
```